# solving differential equation (virus released)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The virus causing dead people to rise as zombies is released now at time $t = 0$. (No one is infected yet). The virus infects people at a rate proportional to the number of people not yet infected, and after $1$ month, $2/3$ of the world is infected with the zombie virus. The population of Earth is $7*10^9$.

How long (in months) until the entire world except one person is infected?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: assuming that dI/dt is the infection rate where (I) is the number of infected people then dI/dt = b * (1/3 * 7*10^9) .

Comment: by integration  I =  b * (1/3 * 7*10^9) * t + C, where b is the proportional constant, using condition in the problem b = 2 and C = 0, but still wrong answer when getting t?

Comment: No, $dI/dt$ is supposed to depend on the number of people not yet infected, not just on the initial population.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since the rate of spreading is proportional to the current population (denoted as $H$ for Humanity):
   $$\frac{dH}{dt} = \lambda H$$
2. Separate variables:
   $$\int_{H_0}^{H}\frac{dH}{H}\ = \int_0^t\lambda dt$$
3. Integrate to get:
   $$\ln{\frac{H}{H_0}} = \lambda t$$
   $$H = H_0 e^{\lambda t}$$
4. Substitute $H(1)$ to get the constant value $\lambda = \ln{\frac{1}{3}}$:
   $$H(t) = 3^{-t}H_0$$
5. Then solve for time given $H(\tau) = 1$:
   $$t = \log_3 (H_0)$$